# Less verbose multiband masking in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I want to mask all pixels above a threshold in a multiband image. If any band is over threshold, that pixel is masked. I can do this using `.and` to apply logic to each band, but is there a less verbose way to accomplish this? Not a big deal for a the three band image example below, but cumbersome to type for an image with many bands.

```
var thresh = 5000
var image = ee.Image('COPERNICUS/S2_SR/20170328T083601_20170328T084228_T35RNK')
var maskImage = image.select(['B2','B3','B4']).lt(thresh) // 3 band image, each band has value of 1 or 0

// using `.and` to ensure all bands below threshold 
var masterMask = maskImage.select('B2')
  .and(maskImage.select('B3'))
  .and(maskImage.select('B4')) 
  .rename('masterMask')
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Fcaseyengstrom%2Freprex%3Amultiband_mask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reduce using a max reducer to find pixels where any band meets the criteria.

```
var mask = image.select(['B2','B3','B4']).gt(thresh).reduce(ee.Reducer.max())
```